# How to modify a row and column in a 2x2 matrix?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm having trouble understanding how to point at coordinates in a 2x2 matrix in assembly.

This is my code:

```
matrix     db '0','0','0'   ; I define 3x3 matrix
row1       db '0','5','0'
row2       db '0','0','0'

; I modify item "A1"
mov bx, 0
mov si, 0
mov matrix[BX][SI], 'x'
```

I noticed that increasing bx, points to the next column/byte but I don't understand what value must I asign to SI so I can point to another row.

For example how can I modify the byte in the middle of the matrix (5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use SI to select the row, then you need to set it to rowIndex*3.  Note that the syntax "matrix[BX][SI]" does not indicate a 2-dimensional array as it does in higher-level languages.  It's synonymous with "matrix[BX + SI]".  The middle element in your matrix has an offset of 4, so you could access it by setting BX to 1 and SI to 3, although it would be more conventional to use BX to select the row.